# Print over Current Line in Python Shell

Tags: python, shell, python-3.x, console

I'm trying to make a percentage text that displays a progress amount but i'm trying to avoid the percentages printing out like this:

`Progress: 10%
Progress: 11%
Progress: 12%
Progress: 13%`

How can erase and write over the current line? Iv'e tried using the \r and \b characters but neither seems to work. Every single thing I found before has been for either for Python 2 or Unix so i'm not even sure which of those is the problem (if even one of them) because i'm not using either. Does anyone know how I can do this with Python 3 running Windows 7? This is the unworking code that I have currently, but I've tried plenty of other things.

```
print('Progress: {}%'.format(solutions//possibleSolutions),flush=True,end="\r")
```

EDIT:

This is not a problem if I'm executing the program from command prompt so I don't think it is a problem with windows. I tried updating Python from what i was using previously (3.4.1) to the latest v3.4.3 and the issue is the same.

Heres a screenshot of the problem:
[image]
This is the best I can do at taking a screenshot of the issue. It appears as if each time I move the cursor farther to the left (passed one of the Progress:'s) that the gray area between the text and the cursor gets larger

## EDIT 2: The problem is that IDLE does not support ASCII control codes. Solution: Use a different IDE.

Comment: Please remove your boldfaced lie.  Your post `https://bugs.python.org/issue24572` on 2015-07-05 21:45 EDT was answered, according to my calculation, 79 minutes later with a reference to `https://bugs.python.org/issue23220`, which explains the situation in some detail.

Comment: For those not do not want to follow the second link above, the 'crap' behavior is the behavior of tcl/tk combined with that of the underlying os.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy I wouldn't describe IDLE as crap just because it doesn't support ASCII control codes. As quoted from Padraic Cunningham, "there are a lot of things that just don't work in idle" and "idle is really just an introductory tool, I used it for about 5 minutes when I started before moving to pycharm and ipython." I didn't mean for anyone to get offended but at the time the "answer" was just a simple link to a similar question without much info on whether or not the feature would be added, and still it doesn't seem like IDLE is any closer to supporting the ASCII control codes?

Comment: Two final comments.  1. I am an unpaid volunteer. I look at new issues once a week when the new issues report comes out.  You have no right to expect more from me.  2. SO is for questions and fact-based answers.  Flamebait opinions are against both the letter and spirit of the rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use print:

```
print('Progress: {}%'.format(solutions),flush=True,end="\r")
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. It prints out like this: Progress: 4%Progress: 12%Progress: 24%Progress: 40%Progress: 60%Progres

Comment: @kmecpp, using `print('Progress: {}%'.format(solutions),flush=True,end="\r")`?

Comment: You can also try `print('\rProgress: {}%'.format(solutions),flush=True,end="")`

Comment: still no, does the same thing. I actually did notice something very weird when copying the text though... they appear to be like ghost characters or something? Do you have any idea what this could be?

Comment: where are you running this from?

Comment: It's actually the opposite. I just tested it and it works fine in command prompt but not in the python shell which is where i need it primarily

Comment: Why do you need it in the python shell?

Comment: Its not absolutely necessary but that's where i'm going to be running the program and its also only the only place the program is going to be used.

Comment: `print('\rProgress: {}%'.format(i),flush=True,end="")` works fine for me using a python shell. I don't quite get how you are running an application  in the interpreter though

Comment: What OS and version of python are you using? I posted a screenshot of the problem i'm having in the shell

Comment: OS is Ubuntu,  are you running this from idle?

Comment: Yes sorry, I posted a screenshot

Comment: Idle is to put it bluntly, crap. I would suggest using pycharm community edition  ide or using ipython.

Comment: +1 for a fix but its not really a solution. I do kinda like IDLE and I'm not really developing any huge applications so its really enough. I posted a bug report so ill see if they fix it, but in the meantime i guess ill just use pycharm

Comment: I would still recommend trying out  ipython at least, it is lightweight and has a multitude of really cool features.

Comment: It looked a little weird but I guess ill check it out

Comment: @kmecpp, idle is a strange beast, it replaces stdout with it's own stream, there are a lot of things that just don't work in idle, I guarantee after a few weeks using ipython you will never want to see idle again

Comment: Lol, if there's one thing i like about IDLE its the simplicity. The only thing I really use Python for is math-ish stuff. I haven't even had a need for object oriented programming in python so I thought IDLE suited me well. I'm optimistic about the IDEs though. For some reason my program even ran like 100x faster o.0 I was completely blown away by this since I don't see that has anything to do with the printing differences because it doesn't even output that often.

Comment: idle is really just an introductory tool, I used it for about 5 minutes when I started before moving to pycharm and ipython. If you are doing math-ish stuff you will like ipython, there are lots of ipython magic commands to work with numpy etc...

Answer (score 0):

You can't use '\r' and '\b' in IDLE. If you want to use it, try adding these lines at the start of your program:

```
import sys
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
```

and running idle with this batch script:

```
@echo off
echo Running IDLE...
py -m idlelib
```

then, you see output in cmd window and there are '\r' and '\b'.

Answer (score 0):

Use the character `'\r'` for the `print` function. Default is `'\n'`.

`'\r'` stands for carriage return, `'\n'` means new line.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a new class called `Printer` like this:

```
class Printer():
    def __init__(self, data):
        sys.stdout.write("\r\x1b[K"+data.__str__())
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

Then, let's say you want to print the progress of a `for` loop:

```
for i in range(0, 100):
        p = i * 100
        output = "%d%% of the for loop completed" % p
        Printer(output)
```